# Setting cookies before browser.get

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Our (PHP) application requires certain cookies to be set in order to load an Angular.js client app. If the cookies are not set an exception is thrown and error page is shown.

This means in order to run E2E tests we need to set the cookies, but the following fails because Protractor is trying to find Angular right after the `browser.get` call (it's not there because the exception was thrown).

```
browser.get('http://' + domain + '/');
browser.manage().addCookie('foo', 'boo', '/', domain);
```

I tried to call `browser.get` after setting the cookies:

```
browser.manage().addCookie('foo', 'boo', '/', domain);
browser.get('http://' + domain + '/');
```

But this produces the following error:

> Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': Cookies are
>   disabled inside 'data:' URLs.

Is there a way how to handle this situation? Perhaps to tell Protractor not to check for Angular when doing the first `browser.get` call or somehow set cookies for our domain before calling getting the URL?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found the solution in the [Protractor Getting Started](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#setting-up-the-system-under-test) doc:

```
browser.driver.get('http://' + domain + '/');
browser.manage().addCookie('foo', 'boo', '/', domain);
```

Note the `browser.driver.get` instead of `browser.get`. This will prevent Protractor looking for the Angular app and cookies can be set. I then use another `browser.get` inside of `it` statement.

Comment: Thanks for writing the example on how to use the webdriver.WebDriver.Options by calling `.manage()`. Because the link you provided does not give any clue on how to use that specific API.

Comment: I've been finding the protractor documentation in general to be incomplete or wrong, examples like these are extremely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: For those seeing this in 2019, `browser.manage().addCookie()` is now expecting an object.
     
    `browser.manage().addCookie({name: 'foo', value: 'bar'})`

Answer (score 6):

`addCookie` with newer Protractor versions (tested with 5.4.2) takes an object of type `IWebDriverOptionsCookie` instead.

Note: *to fetch the cookie use `getCookies`*

### Example:

```js
browser.manage().addCookie({ name: 'foo', value: 'bar' });
```

### `IWebDriverOptionsCookie` documentation:

```
interface IWebDriverOptionsCookie {
  /** The name of the cookie. */
  name: string;

  /** The cookie value. */
  value: string;

  /** The cookie path. Defaults to "/" when adding a cookie. */
  path?: string;

  /**
   * The domain the cookie is visible to. Defaults to the current browsing
   * context's document's URL when adding a cookie.
   */
  domain?: string;

  /**
   * Whether the cookie is a secure cookie. Defaults to false when adding a new
   * cookie.
   */
  secure?: boolean;

  /**
   * Whether the cookie is an HTTP only cookie. Defaults to false when adding a
   * new cookie.
   */
  httpOnly?: boolean;

  /**
   * When the cookie expires.
   *
   * When adding a cookie, this may be specified in seconds since Unix epoch (January 1, 1970).
   * The expiry will default to 20 years in the future if omitted.
   *
   * The expiry is always returned in seconds since epoch when
   * retrieving cookies from the browser.
   *
   * @type {(!Date|number|undefined)}
   */
  expiry?: number | Date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as `browser.driver.get()` returns a promise, you should take it into account:

```
browser.driver.get('http://' + domain + '/').then(() => {
  browser.manage().addCookie({name: 'foo', value: 'boo'});
});
```

Also notice, in this case you don't need to pass domain value to `addCookie` because protractor will use the current domain by default.